# Erro no instanciamento para classe

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, window-builder

Boa tarde,

Já olhei várias vezes e não entendo o motivo desse erro.
Preciso instanciar a "variável criado" que está no JFrame para a classe UsuarioM.
Só que fica dizendo que em na linha que a "variável criado" precisa ser "java.util.Date" na classe modelo.

**Model**

```
public class UsuarioM {

// Variáveis
private String nome;
private String senha; 
private String grupo;  
private String estado;
private String cpf;
private String criador;
private Date criado;
private Date acesso;

// Getters & Setters
public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}
public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}
public String getSenha() {
    return senha;
}
public void setSenha(String senha) {
    this.senha = senha;
}
public String getGrupo() {
    return grupo;
}
public void setGrupo(String grupo) {
    this.grupo = grupo;
}
public String getEstado() {
    return estado;
}
public void setEstado(String estado) {
    this.estado = estado;
}
public String getCpf() {
    return cpf;
}
public void setCpf(String cpf) {
    this.cpf = cpf;
}
public String getCriador() {
    return criador;
}
public void setCriador(String criador) {
    this.criador = criador;
}
public Date getCriado() {
    return criado;
}
public void setCriado(Date criado) {
    this.criado = criado;
}
public Date getAcesso() {
    return acesso;
}
public void setAcesso(Date acesso) {
    this.acesso = acesso;
}

// Metódos
public UsuarioM() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public UsuarioM(String nome, String senha, String grupo, String estado, String cpf, String criador) {
    this.nome = nome;
    this.senha = senha;
    this.grupo = grupo;
    this.estado = estado;
    this.cpf = cpf;
    this.criador = criador;
}

public UsuarioM(String nome, String senha, String grupo, String estado, String cpf, String criador,
        Date criado) {
    this.nome = nome;
    this.senha = senha;
    this.grupo = grupo;
    this.estado = estado;
    this.cpf = cpf;
    this.criador = criador;
    this.criado = criado;
}
```

}

**DAO**

```
public class UsuarioD {

// Variáveis
private Connection con = ConectarDB.getConexao();    

public void novoUsuario(model.UsuarioM usuarioM){

    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    String sql = "insert into usuario (nome, senha, grupo, estado, cpf, criador, criado) "
            + "values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    try {
        ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, usuarioM.getNome());
        ps.setString(2, usuarioM.getSenha());
        ps.setString(3, usuarioM.getGrupo());
        ps.setString(4, usuarioM.getEstado());
        ps.setString(5, usuarioM.getCpf());
        ps.setString(6, usuarioM.getCriador());
        ps.setDate(7, new Date(usuarioM.getCriado().getTime()));
        ps.execute();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Novo Usuário criado com sucesso!");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

**Jframe**

```
// Captura dos Dados
            String nome = tfNome.getText();
            String senha = new String (pfSenha.getPassword());
            String grupo = (String) cbGrupo.getSelectedItem();
            String estado = (String) cbEstado.getSelectedItem();
            String cpf = ftCPF.getText();
            model.UsuarioM usuarioM = new UsuarioM();
            String criador = usuarioM.getCriador();             

            // Capturar Data e Hora
            java.util.Date criado = new java.util.Date();

            // Verificar se houve erro!
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, criador);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, criado);


            dao.UsuarioD usuarioD = new dao.UsuarioD();
            usuarioM = new UsuarioM(nome, senha, grupo, estado, cpf, criador, criado);
            usuarioD.novoUsuario(usuarioM);
```

Comment: Onde mostra o erro?

Comment: Em jFrame tem a linha:

usuarioM = new UsuarioM(nome, senha, grupo, estado, cpf, criador, criado);

É dito que o "criado" precisa ser "java.util.Date" só que eu preciso que seja Date para que possa ser passado para o PostGre já que na coluna está definido "timestamp".

Comment: Tem certeza que o atributo criado é `java.util.Date`? Tente deixar o nome completo pra testar.

Comment: Image 01: http://postimg.org/image/jh0606grf/

Comment: Image 02: http://postimg.org/image/khvotvjpz/

Comment: Ele exige que seja java.util.Date loL²

Comment: qual são os imports da sua classe UsuarioM?

Comment: Somente: import java.sql.Date;

Comment: Entao é esse o problema. Você está tentando passar java.util.Date para import java.sql.Date.

Comment: Como você quer passar um `util.Date` pra um `sql.Date`?

Comment: Não notei isso. Depois que você perguntou fui olhar kkkkk² Muito obrigado campeão!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está o ocorrendo, pois o construtor da classe **UsuarioM** aceita um **java.sql.Date** e ao instanciar um objeto **UsuarioM** está sendo passado **java.util.Date**.

Altere o import da classe UsuarioM para **java.util.Date**.

Comment: Excelente observação! Muito obrigado!